# Angular filtering with dropdown

Tags: javascript, angular, filtering

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

Some Angular service:

```
items = [
{name: "item1", type: "type1"},
{name: "item2", type: "type2"},
{name: "item3", type: "type2"}
```

];

And some filtering function, which filters an array by type and returns new array.

I haven't got problems with filtering by button like:

```
<button type="button" (click)="Filter('type2')"></button>
```

But I can't do it using dropdown.

UPD: Incorrect explanation.  [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nyn8gf) live demo. Need to filter array with  (change) event at select tag using brandName

Comment: Will you be little more specific about the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `ngModel` to get selected value and `change` event to update the list:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedBrand" (change)="valueSelected()">
  <option *ngFor="let item of brandName">{{ item }}</option>
</select>
```

Then filtering items in the component when value has been changed:

```
public selectedBrand;
public valueSelected() {
    this.goods = this.goodsService.goods.filter(item => item.name === this.selectedBrand);
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-te7wau)

Comment: Thanks, but I  need to filter another array. Incorrectly expressed my thoughts

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was easier than I thought.

Comment: @Shiv, I updated the link to the demo. It was added by someone else and was an exact copy to the demo in the question. I added copied over code from my answer it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

AppComponent.ts file

```
export class AppComponent{

    constructor(){}
    items = [
        {name: "item1", type: "type1"},
        {name: "item2", type: "type2"},
        {name: "item3", type: "type2"}
    ];

makeArr(e){
    console.log(e);
}

}
```

html

```
<select (change)='makeArr($event.target.value)'>
    <option *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

you are having the problem with displaying the value from the object. retrieve the value of the object using `.` or you can use the `[]`